# Configure client-side logging

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

Have a third party SFDC developer who built the Marketing Cloud (MC) connector and wrote the post strings to create records in MC.

Recently, I discovered that several emails of our customers were blocked by ListDetective because email contained "Info@".

I emailed Support about getting some logs for visibility. However, this is something they cannot help with and they suggested adding some client-side error logging in the API post strings to get this information. What are some methods I should consider and look into?

Comment: The integration logs won't help you much here. This list detective is a scarcely documented backend function. To work with info@, admin@ etc you need to create a support ticket with a reason why you send to those address types and a list of localparts (eg info, admin) that you need enabled. By default they are blocked for data quality reasons as the often come from illegitimate sources like scraped address lists. We managed to convince them with the small enterprise business case as those often use generic addresses for direct communication.

Comment: @StephandePaly - I would put this as an answer instead of a comment. This is the correct course of action to be taken.

Comment: @gortonington will do. I'm sometimes not sure if my answers are up to quality expectations because I usually write from mobile where all those linkages etc are a bit of a pain

Answer (score 1):

The integration logs won't help you much here. This list detective is a scarcely documented backend function.

To work with info@, admin@ etc you need to create a support ticket with a reason why you send to those address types and a list of localparts (eg info, admin) that you need enabled.

By default they are blocked for data quality reasons as the often come from illegitimate sources like scraped address lists.

We managed to convince them with the small enterprise business case as those often use generic addresses for direct communication.

Comment: Noted. I agree with the list detective logic even as a precaution. However, I am trying to understand the issue and know just how many subscribers have been blocked so I can email support about specific email addresses to unblock.

Comment: @JsonNoob: By chance I stumbled upon a solution for your identification issue: The tracking extract functionality also includes "not sent" as event type to extract which has a field "reason". So you do an extract of "not sent" and in your export file you filter out those that have list detective as reason: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5

Comment: Documentation excerpt: "Tracking extracts retrieve data before sends execute. The data includes information on any subscriber listed as undeliverable or excluded by List Detective." https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null